# How do you express -1 nanosecond in a timespec structure?

Tags: c++, datetime, math, time

The timespec structure is defined as:

```
struct timespec {
    time_t tv_sec;        /* seconds */
    long   tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds [0 .. 999999999] */
};
```

The two fields are signed numbers. I can easily define "now" as something such as:

```
timespec now{ 1'629'659'718, 564'223'121 };
```

I can also define a null `timespec`:

```
timespec nulltime = {};
```

But looking at the structure, it sounds like we can't really express a negative number. Is that correct?

The nanoseconds field has to be a positive number between 0 and 999'999'999 (as shown above and as mentioned in various man pages where functions will return EINVAL if this value is out of these bounds).

So the only solution I could think of is to use a negative number in `tv_sec`. However, I don't see how to represent -0.000000001 (-1 nanosecond) in that case... since I would need to put at least -1 second:

```
timespec minus_one_nano{ -1, 1 };            // this sounds like -1.000000001
timespec minus_one_nano{ -1, 999'999'999 };  // this is probably -1.999999999
```

Is there something about such or is it expected that all numbers in a `timespec` are positive?

---

Where did my `{ -1, 999'999'999 }` come from?

Say I start with 1.3 seconds:

```
timespec a{ 1, 300'000'000 };
```

I want to subtract 1 nanosecond, I do:

```
timespec b{ a.tv_sec, a.tv_sec - 1}; // b = {1, 299'999'999}
```

When I start with 0 nanoseconds:

```
timespec a{ 3, 0 };   // 3.0s
timespec b{ 2, 999'999'999 };   // a - 1ns = 2.99999999s
```

Applying the same math to 0.0s I get:

```
timespec b{ -1, 999'999'999 };  // zero - 1ns
```

So the math works with such negative numbers, but to display that number, I'd have to compute the opposite in some way (i.e. do `0 - b` and then print "-" + the positive number in `b`). It feels convoluted.

Comment: I don't think it's possible but perhaps you can work around it by using `std::chrono::nanoseconds` instead?

Comment: It seems like you've figured it out. The total nanoseconds should be `tv_sec * 1'000'000'000 + tv_nsec`, right? So `{-1, 999'999'999}` seems right to me: `-1'000'000'000 + 999'999'999 == -1`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The thing is I want to use it with the `pthread_cond_timedwait()` so I need a compatible structure.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Why not use the standard C++ thread support library and use [`std::condition_variable::wait_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) or [`wait_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until)?

Comment: FWIW, the C11 standard explicitly stipulates that both members are >=0. You can't ask `pthread_cond_timedwait` to wait for negative time anyway, so it is unclear why you would want this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually *use* a negative time with any system/library call, so if you just want a notion of a negative time (eg, that you can add to an absolute time or an interval to get a positive time), you can use any representation you like -- having just the tv_sec field be (possibly) negative and having the tv_nsec alway be mod 1e9 is fine.